# Trapped inside car due to live wire

Tags: electricity

My physics teacher said that if a person is trapped in a car due to live wire that is touching the outside metal of the car, then it is safe for the person to touch the outside metal of the car as long as the person stays in the car. Why is that true?

Answer (score 0):

Because while you are inside the car, you are isolated from electrical ground by the car's tires, which are nonconductive. This means that if you touch the metal of the car, there is no conductive path available between your body and ground and so no current can flow through you.

Answer (score 0):

It is for the same reason that a bird sitting on a high voltage wire does not receive an electric shock as long as the bird is not also touching something conductively connected to the earth. All parts of you (and the bird) are at the same electrical potential. The potential difference is between the wire (and the outside metal of the car touching the wire) and ground. The car is insulated from ground by its tires.

If, on the other hand, you are touching the outside metal with your hand and are touching the ground with another part of your body that is inadequately insulated, there will be high voltage across your body. The resulting current flow through your body could result in a lethal electric shock.

Hope this helps.